# How to make UILabel in Swift a circle

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make a UILabel in Swift a perfect circle. I am currently using the following:

```
pResult.layer.masksToBounds = true
pResult.layer.cornerRadius = 125
```

The problem with this is that it works fine on 6s plus but any other size it does not become a circle. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Circled corners or a full circle? Anyway, assuming that you want the second option, you should constraint the aspect ratio (width:height) to 1:1 on the storyboard so the label is always a square. Then, in the code, you can just do something like

```
pResult.layer.cornerRadius = pResult.frame.width/2
```

to always make it a perfect circle, no matter what screen size it will be on.

Comment: I would go for calculating the corner radius: let radius = min(yourButton.frame.size.width, yourButton.frame.size.height) / 2.0

Comment: It will just result in a rounded rect if the label itself isnt properly sized, but it's the best way to do it if he wants it , yes

Comment: you should also add pResult.layer.masksToBounds = true

Comment: Didn't work for me. Adding `pResult.layer.masksToBounds = true` fixed it.

Answer (score 11):

If you you want to make perfect circle then first make sure your label width and height are same.

```
pResult.layer.cornerRadius = CGRectGetWidth(pResult.frame)/2
pResult.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410818-cornerradius)

Answer (score 5):

If you are using swift 3 then please try this:

```
lblRoundDot.layer.cornerRadius = lblRoundDot.frame.width/2
lblRoundDot.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on the previous answer, but this one in Swift 4.2 :

```
    label.layer.cornerRadius =  label.frame.width/2
    label.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//You can provide UserdefiendRunTimeConstraints on the Label using Storyboard or XIB  Select label and give
```

(Ex. Your Label Width=100 & Height=100)

```
 KeyPath =layer.cornerRadius
 Type = Number
 Value = 50

 KeyPath = layer.masksToBounds
 Type = Boolean
 Value = True

 KeyPath = layer.borderWidth
 Type = Number
 Value = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Depend on the answer of @FruitAddict, i would like to improve it more perfect. You should use .height property instead .width cause in case the length of label be longer (the text increase) this code won't working. And the code will be like this:

```
pResult.layer.cornerRadius = pResult.frame.height / 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Create UILabel extension

```
extension UILabel {
    func addBadge(badgeCount: String) {
       self.text = badgeCount
        self.textColor = UIColor.white
        self.textAlignment = .center
        self.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0)
       self.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * self.bounds.size.width
        self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
       
    }
```