# How to make a label to be a circle in Swift4?

Tags: ios, swift

timerLabel is the label that I'm trying to change it into a circle. This line code is not working the way that I desire:

```
timerLabel.layer.cornerRadius = timerLabel.frame.width/2
```

Comment: Your question is too broad. Do you want to make label look like a clock ? Or you just want to make label round by applying corner radius ?

Comment: Explain the behaviour you observed. Explain the behaviour you want.

Comment: A lot depends on where that line of code is. Show full context.

Comment: @elarcoiris Thanks I found a solution there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my issue in this already been asked post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46066815/8451094 .
Thanks @elarcoiris

```
lblRoundDot.layer.cornerRadius = lblRoundDot.frame.width/2

lblRoundDot.layer.masksToBounds = true
```